# Windows 8 Open File dialog (metro apps) navigate quickly to specific folder

Tags: windows-8

I've been using Windows 8 for about 4 months now and the more I use it the more frustrated I become. I'm not a technical newbie by any stretch, but I find many things about Windows 8 quite frustrating, considering everything in Windows 7 seemed so easy and intuitive for me.

This question is about the Open File dialog. That is, when I am in a program and I need to select a file, it uses the Windows 8 common dialog for selecting a file. Before, there was a text box where I could copy and past in a full path to quickly jump to any folder I wanted. Now, I do not see that option. So, since I have quite a deep and complex folder structure, it takes me a very, very long time to navigate to the folder I want. In the end, I usually drag the file I want to open to the desktop, open from there and when done move it back, which is far from nice.

Is there a way to quickly jump to a folder if I know the path (e.g., `C:\Files\Some Stuff\MyData\Project 1\Sub Project 2\This folder`)?

**Edit:** I should have been more clear. I'm talking about full-screen (Metro) apps like Chrome. With non-metro apps you get a standard open file dialog which works just like before but my concern is with the metro UI dialog which does not offer the user any way to enter a filename.

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows 8 Metro file dialogs has no such options. It is a pain to navigate to folders. However, you have made a really good point. Concluding, this is NOT POSSIBLE!

Answer (score 0):

I just opened WordPad on my Windows 8.1 PC and clicked on File, Open.

In the resulting dialog box, I can write out a direct location on the hard drive (or paste the entire path) both in the top field where you see "This PC > Documents" by default, and in the "File name:" field. As far as I know, Wordpad uses the built in file selection dialog box in Windows 8, so yours should behave similarly.

To be more explicit in the directions, after you type the location or paste the location, press Enter and it should go directly to that directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been clearer. I am just talking about metro UI apps like Chrome. I've updated my question accordingly to prevent further confusion.